# Sort an collection keys base on Array with pure JS or with Lodash

Tags: arrays, sorting, collections, lodash

I want to sort the `products` collection keys based on the Array `order`. And I'm expecting the output like `expecting`. Does anyone have an easy solution in pure JS or with Lodash library?

**You can find the source code from** [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/GeneralInsistentCondition)

Thanks

```js
const _ = require('lodash')

var products = [
  {cgst: "18", item: "UPS V Guard Slender 1450", price: "2800", sgst: "18", stock: 2},
  {cgst: "9", item: "UPS V Guard Prime 1450", price: "6000", sgst: "9", stock: 30}
]
var order = ['item', 'price', 'cgst', 'sgst', 'stock']

// Expecting output
var expecting = [
  {item: "UPS V Guard Slender 1450", price: "2800", cgst: "18", sgst: "18", stock: 2},
  {item: "UPS V Guard Prime 1450", price: "6000", cgst: "9", sgst: "9", stock: 30}
]
```

Comment: Why do you need to sort the object's properties?

Comment: I want to convert into a CSV file using Papa Parse. So, I want to keep the data same as the Array `order`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is actually ordering the CSV fields, and not object properties. 
The [**`Papa.unparse()`**](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#json-to-csv) method accepts an object with `fields` and `data`. You can pass the order to it:

```js
var products = [
  {cgst: "18", item: "UPS V Guard Slender 1450", price: "2800", sgst: "18", stock: 2},
  {cgst: "9", item: "UPS V Guard Prime 1450", price: "6000", sgst: "9", stock: 30}
]
var order = ['item', 'price', 'cgst', 'sgst', 'stock']

var csv = Papa.unparse({
 fields: order,
 data: products
});

console.log(csv);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.5.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
```

**If you really need order object properties' order:**

You can [**`Array.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [**`_.pick()`**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pick) to get the objects properties in the correct order.

**Note:** in ES6 object properties have an order, but it has some quirks. See this [article](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html).

```js
var products = [
  {cgst: "18", item: "UPS V Guard Slender 1450", price: "2800", sgst: "18", stock: 2},
  {cgst: "9", item: "UPS V Guard Prime 1450", price: "6000", sgst: "9", stock: 30}
]
var order = ['item', 'price', 'cgst', 'sgst', 'stock']

// Expecting output
var expecting = [
  {item: "UPS V Guard Slender 1450", price: "2800", cgst: "18", sgst: "18", stock: 2},
  {item: "UPS V Guard Prime 1450", price: "6000", cgst: "9", sgst: "9", stock: 30}
]

var result = products.map(o => _.pick(o, order))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I saw that. The two methods are working great! Thank you so much. And It will be the shortest solution that you did it with `map()` and `_.pick()`.

Comment: I would use the Para.unparse() solution since it will be less error prone, and probably more performant.